# 400 error - The given location is invalid

Tags: json, api, okhttp

I am trying to retrieve JSON data via an API and parsing it into my Android. I am trying to log the JSON data retrieved but I keep getting a `"400 error - given location is invalid."` The parameters to access the API seem correct but I am not sure why I can't retrieve the data.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    temperatureLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureLabel);
    timeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeLabel);
    refreshButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshImage);

    final double latitude = -104.8319;
    final double longtitude = 39.7294;

    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getWeatherForecast(latitude, longtitude);
        }
    });

    getWeatherForecast(latitude, longtitude);
}

    public void getWeatherForecast(double latitude, double longtitude) {

    String apiKey = "SECRET-KEY;
    String forecastURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + latitude + ","
            + longtitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

        //Build and HTTP request
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastURL).build();

        //Make an Api call
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        alertUserError();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            try {

                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                Log.e(TAG, "JASON DATA" + jsonData);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    mcurrentWeather = getCurrentWeatherDetails(jsonData);
                    // You want to update the display In the UI.
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateDisplay();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "API call failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "JSONexception Caught");
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    alertUserError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check what request you send to the `API` and what the `API` sends to you, then you should implement [OkHttp logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor). It's simple and easy to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have deleted your secret key from your answer and replaced it with "SECRET-KEY". DarkSky is only free 1000 requests per day, so someone could grab that key and reuse it. You'd have to pay for it.

I would to go to https://darksky.net/dev/account and reset the secret key to avoid risks.

Second, your coordinates are swapped. You currently have

```
final double latitude = -104.8319;
final double longtitude = 39.7294;
String forecastURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" 
        + latitude + ","
        + longtitude;
```

That result of:

https://api.darksky.net/forecast/SECRET-KEY/-104.8319,39.7294?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,flags,alerts

is then "400, Location invalid" because there is no location in the world with latitude -104 and longitude 39.

The correct one is

```
final double latitude = 39.7294;
final double longtitude = -104.8319;
```

Then your `urlString` is:

https://api.darksky.net/forecast/SECRET-KEY/39.7294,-104.8319?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,flags,alerts

which outputs in the browser:

```
{
"latitude":39.7294,
"longitude":-104.8319,
"timezone":"America/Denver",
"currently":{
    "time":1583068320,
    "summary":"Mostly Cloudy",
    "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
    "nearestStormDistance":9,
    "nearestStormBearing":145,
    "precipIntensity":0,
    "precipProbability":0,
    "temperature":37.32,
    "apparentTemperature":33.14,
    "dewPoint":18.62,
    "humidity":0.46,
    "pressure":1011.5,
    "windSpeed":5.24,
    "windGust":7.61,
    "windBearing":157,
    "cloudCover":0.87,
    "uvIndex":0,
    "visibility":10,
    "ozone":309},
"offset":-7
}
```

P.S: Notice I included the `exclude` query item to shorten the response to show the example. Delete that part and you will have all the response, with minutely, daily and so on fields.